# Setting clipboard contents to custom data

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, clipboard

I'm copying some XML to `Clipboard` that makes sense to my app only and I do not want other applications to be able to paste. Using the following line:

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText, myXML);
```

I can copy and paste thing correctly, but other text editors can paste it as well. I was expecting there would be a `DataFormats.Custom` for this situation but there isn't.

Is there a way to send data to Clipboard that is available to my app only?

*(I'm assuming that applications check available DataFormats before fetching clipboard content and do not fetch them if the returned format is not something they can handle. For example Notepad would do nothing if I use Paste command after copying an image)*

Comment: Does a custom instance of DataFormat work?

Comment: @someone: No `SetData` does not accept `DataFormat` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Clipboard.SetData` expects simple string as first argument, `DataFormat` is not an enum. So you can do just this:

```
Clipboard.SetData("my_custom_format", myXml);
```

Then you can check if clipboard contains your data with

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsData("my_custom_format")) {
    var xml = Clipboard.GetData("my_custom_format");
}
```

And you won't be able to paste this data into other editors like Notepad.

Comment: Ouch. Should have checked this. Let me try.

Comment: Precisely correct. Feeling a bit dumb. Thanks for quick and accurate answer.